# Getting AWS Security group rule ID

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

Does anyone know how to get this Security group rule ID via AWS SDK?

[image]

I use this

```
aws ec2 describe-security-groups --group-ids sg-0ad9f9694512344
```

but does not seem to return anything that starts with sgr-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Security Group Rule IDs were introduced only recently (July 2021).

See: [Easily Manage Security Group Rules with the New Security Group Rule ID | AWS News Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/easily-manage-security-group-rules-with-the-new-security-group-rule-id/)

Therefore, **your SDK might need updating**.

I checked the AWS SDK for Python (boto3) and it already has [`describe_security_group_rules()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_security_group_rules) available.

The AWS CLI also has: [`describe-security-group-rules`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-security-group-rules.html)